# How to Make Session in ASP.Net MVC but not expired?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
var user=Db.GetUser();

Session["User"]=user;

var user=Session["user"] as List<User>;
```

Comment: Please add more description about your problem, what is current behavior and expected.

Comment: I want not expired session in mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume you are looking for session expiration time.

This is a link to [HttpSessionState collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_SessionState_HttpSessionState_Timeout)

And you can change the time through your code as well:

```
Session.Timeout = 200; //in minutes
```

BTW: more information about [sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6d60d381-6521-4e1d-9089-da6464f2a9bc)

**Regarding the comments**, max time cannot be more than 525600 minutes, so:

```
Session.Timeout = 525600;
```

Or through web config (that is easy BTW) as mentioned in the links

But you have to take into account that then all session will be in the server memory at some point IIS will recycle the app pool. *And you will lose all sessions, even the active one*. And moreover, you will face huge performance issues as well.

I would not recommend keeping the session long. You just check if session expired then call DB again.

Comment: Bro i want not expired for every time

Comment: What happens if IIS abandon the session? Or restarted?

Comment: @user10397864 Per the documentation he linked, the max timeout is 1 year.

Comment: How to max time ?